# Extract return code from IIS powershell command

Tags: windows, powershell, iis

let's say I run this command:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty system.web/sessionState -pspath MACHINE/WEBROOT -name regenerateExpiredSessionID -value WrongValue
```

I will get the following error, but `$lastExitCode` returns `0`.

> Set-WebConfigurationProperty : String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
>   At line:1 char:1

Is there any way to extract more informative return code to ensure that operation succeed/failed?

..and if failed, to get the exact return code? (as `appcmd` with the same command returns `13`, which is `ERROR_INVALID_DATA`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [about_Automatic_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6):

> `$LASTEXITCODE`
>
> Contains the exit code of the last Windows-based program that was run.

Check `$ERROR` variable rather.

Read [About CommonParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-6) as well; at least, pay your attention to common parameters

- `ErrorAction` (`ea`): *overrides the value of the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable for the current command*.
- `ErrorVariable` (`ev`): *stores error messages about the command in the specified variable and in the `$Error` automatic variable*.

Getting it together: the following code snippet should display `FormatException`

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty system.web/sessionState -pspath MACHINE/WEBROOT `
   -name regenerateExpiredSessionID -value $WrongValue `
   -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable a
if ($a.Count -ne 0) { Write-Host $a.CategoryInfo.Reason } else { Write-Host 'Success' }
```